# WPF Bottomless DataGrid keeps expanding downward

Tags: wpf, scroll, datagrid

I've got this `Grid` which contains a `TabControl` with a number of `TabItem`.
Each `TabItem` loads a `UserControl`.

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem>
            <local:UsersControl/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

In this specific `UserControl` I placed a `Grid` with nested a `DockPanel`, left side for menu, right for content.
On the right side are loaded a `Border` containing a single `UserControl` relative to the selection on the menu on the left.

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
        <Border>
            <UserControl Content="{Binding MainDock, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Finally, the `UserControl` consists of a `StackPanel` which contains a `TextBlock` and a `ScrollViewver` with inside a `DataGrid`.

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock/>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <DataGrid>
            <!-- datagrid stuff -->
        </DataGrid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</StackPanel>
```

The problem consist in the latest `StackPanel` being bottomless and expanding well over the bottom of the window application, which never activate the `ScrollViewer` hiding part of the grid data, when there are enough rows.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Use a Grid or a DockPanel instead of a StackPanel.

Comment: DockPanel did the job. I had to add DockPanel.Dock="Top" to the top elements but it was a small price to pay
Thanks.